# Output parameter in joining two matrices?

Tags: output, join

I have to join two matrices.

`$cat mat1` :

```
sample  gen1    gen2    gen3    gen4  
pt1     1       4       7       10  
pt3     5       5       8       11 
pt4     3       6       9       12
```

`$cat mat2` :

```
sample  age gender  stage   etc  
pt0     5   m       stage1  poi  
pt1     6   f       stage2  bmn  
pt2     9   m       stage3  yup   
pt3     7   f       stage4  qaz  
pt4     6   f       stage2  bmn
```

`$join -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 2.4 mat1 mat2` :

```
sample gen1 gen2 gen3 stage  
pt1    1    4    7    stage2  
pt3    5    5    8    stage4  
pt4    3    6    9    stage2
```

My actual matrix `mat1` has around 20,000 columns, so it is not feasible to write 1.1 1.2 ..1.20,000 what variation to `-o` parameter can be used to state all columns of matrix one and only one column from `mat2` is required as the final merged matrix.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such option for `-o` (from `man join`):

```
-o FORMAT
       obey FORMAT while constructing output line

   FORMAT is one or more comma  or  blank  separated
   specifications,  each  being  `FILENUM.FIELD'  or `0'.  Default FORMAT
   outputs the join field, the remaining fields from FILE1, the remaining
   fields  from  FILE2,  all separated by CHAR.  If FORMAT is the keyword
   'auto', then the first line of each  file  determines  the  number  of
   fields output for each line.
```

Use `cut` to select the appropriate columns first and then join:

```
join -t ' ' mat1 <(cut -f1,4 mat2)
```

(that is a tab character between the quotes: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>),
or for all the columns up to 19999 of `mat1` you can do:

```
cut -f-19999 mat1 | join -t ' ' - <(cut -f1,4 mat2)
```

Answer (score 0):

One common way to handle tasks like this is to use `awk`instead of `join`: first constructing an associative array from the entries in one file, and then looking up the corresponding values when processing the other file, using the common column as key. In your case for example

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {stage[$1]=$4; next;}; {print $0,stage[$1]}' mat2 mat1
sample  gen1    gen2    gen3    gen4   stage
pt1     1       4       7       10   stage2
pt3     5       5       8       11  stage4
pt4     3       6       9       12   stage2
```